# Packed chain with gravity top

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two view that are fit at the top and bottom of the screen and I have a Recycler view that will sit between them but there is one view that much be packed with recyclview vertically. Something like this

[image]

I have to use constraint layout to achieve this. I have tried to achieve this with using packed-chain but that puts the view in center of screen not align to the the top view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the bias of the chain to zero and that will position the *RecyclerView* and the view below it to the top of the center area. Something like this:

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Bottom View"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Top"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="View"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think the key point here is that the top and bottom views do not have to be part of the chain.

You could also, maybe, do the same without the chain by constraining the tops of the center views.

Comment: Actually it will pass though the bottom of screen. Please check this https://ibb.co/6WH72WQ

Comment: @user2934930 Then specify `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` for the _RecyclerView_. I have updated the answer.

Comment: could you please also explain the other approach without using chain ?

Comment: @user2934930  Since your _RecyclerView_ can grow beyond the bounds of the screen, I think that you will need to use the chain to ensure that it stays without bounds. I said the you "may" be able to do it without the chain if this was not the case (you didn't state either way.). Does my answer not work for you as it's stated?

Comment: this should work for me I was just curious to know the other way that you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

The point is not having bottom constraints for these top, RecyclerView and tiny view.

And for your passing through problem, you can use `Guideline` for your RecycleView's bottom constraint.

This is an example. You should modify to fit to your actual situation. Especially about widths or heights which have px sized may be replaced with `wrap_content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="400dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/tinyView"
        android:layout_width="240px"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I my case views can't have the specific height so not bottom constrainst will pass through the screen.

Comment: @user2934930 I updated my answer with `Guideline`.